# Can a couple move while having sex

Tags: halal-haram

What I mean is in movies while a couple is having sex the sometimes move from room to room in Islam can the couple move around or not? Also, what is the max time to have sex(how long)? what is the max age to have sex at?

Comment: This is three separate questions. Also, why would you think moving from room to room could be haram, and why do you think there might be a maximum age?

Answer (score -2):

No problem. Only haram is anal sex and sex during menses. And some Scholar differ about oral sex.